How to get the notification text from the ViewModel?
My application is going to get a new string from the ViewModel every few hours and show it to the user as a notification text. The problem is that I don't know how to get the string from the ViewModel and send it to the notification.
this is my viewModel|:
class ListViewModel(private val listManager: ListStateManager) : ViewModel() {
    private val _currentValue = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val currentValue: StateFlow<Int> get() = _currentValue

    private val items = listOf(
        "",
        "notification text 1",
        "notification text 2",
        "notification text 3",
        "notification text 4",
        "notification text 5"
    )


    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val index = listManager.currentIndex.first()
            _currentValue.value = index
        }
    }



    fun getCurrentItem(): String {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val nextIndex = (_currentValue.value + 1) % items.size // increase index and then return value
            _currentValue.value = nextIndex
            listManager.updateIndex(nextIndex)
        }
        return items[_currentValue.value]


    }
}

I used a "DataStore" library to preserve my values ​​across subsequent runs:
class ListStateManager(private val context: Context) {
    val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore(name = "app_preferences")
    private val CURRENT_INDEX_KEY = intPreferencesKey("current_index_key")

    // read current index
    val currentIndex: Flow<Int> = context.dataStore.data
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[CURRENT_INDEX_KEY] ?: 0 // default value
        }

    // update index
    suspend fun updateIndex(newIndex: Int) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[CURRENT_INDEX_KEY] = newIndex
        }
    }
}

and this in my MainActivity:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var listViewModel: ListViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

     val listManager = ListStateManager(this)
        val factory = ListViewModelFactory(listManager)
        listViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(ListViewModel::class.java)



        setContent {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            LanguageNotifTheme {
                createNotificationChannel(this)
                scheduleNotificationWorker(this, listViewModel)

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    RequestNotificationPermission(context)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ListViewModelFactory(
    private val listManager: ListStateManager
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ListViewModel::class.java)) {
            return ListViewModel(listManager) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}

fun scheduleNotificationWorker(context: Context, viewModel: ListViewModel) {
  val notificationText = viewModel.getCurrentItem()

    val workData = workDataOf("NOTIFICATION_TEXT" to notificationText)
    val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationWorker>(
        16, TimeUnit.MINUTES
    ).setInputData(workData)
        .build()


    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        "notification_work",
        androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, 
        workRequest
    )
}





// this is a worker! we can not use  viewModel in Worker class!
class NotificationWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
 val notificationText = inputData.getString("NOTIFICATION_TEXT") ?: "notification default text"
        sendNotification()
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun sendNotification(notificationText: String) {
        val notificationManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "channel_id")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_plus)
            .setContentTitle("Scheduled Notification")
            .setContentText(notificationText)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .build()

        notificationManager.notify(
            System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(),
            notification
        ) // System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(): create unique id for notification
    }
}



The application needs to get the text from the viewmodel every 16 minutes and send it to the notification.In the code I have written, a notification is displayed every 16 minutes, but the problem is that it displays a duplicate text every time and the new text is not replaced. I need to get and display new text from the ViewModel every time.

"The application needs to get the text from the viewmodel" -- no, the application needs to get the text. Use the viewmodel solely for your activity/fragment/composables. Have the NotificationWorker get the text from the ListStateManager. "I need to be able to access the fun getCurrentItem() in the viewmodel to both increment the index for the next string and access its text" -- no, you need to be able to increment the index and get the text. That does not have to be the job of a viewmodel.

I have changed the code. The problem is that the notification only displays the first text every time and the content of the notification does not change.

Problem solved. I removed the viewmodel and replaced it with the following code
  override fun doWork(): Result {
    val sharedPreferences = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val lastIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt("lastIndex", -1)

    val phrases = listOf(
        "Hello!", "Good morning!", "How are you?", "Nice to meet you!", "Good luck!",
        "See you soon!", "Take care!", "Have a great day!", "Welcome!", "Congratulations!",
        "Happy Birthday!", "Safe travels!", "Enjoy your meal!", "Sweet dreams!", "Get well soon!",
        "Well done!", "Thank you!", "I love you!", "Good night!", "Goodbye!"
    )

    val nextIndex = (lastIndex + 1) % phrases.size
    val nextPhrase = phrases[nextIndex]

    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.putInt("lastIndex", nextIndex)
    editor.apply()

    sendNotification(nextPhrase)

    return Result.success()
}

